# MFC - Change CMFCMenuBar contents during runtime

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created an MFC application which has a CMFCMenuBar object to handle the main menu.
During the initialization of the software, this object will use the default IDR_MAINFRAME.

```
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;

if (!pMainFrame || !pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    delete pMainFrame;
    return FALSE;
}
```

And in the CMainFrame class, the default initialization is as follow:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CMDIFrameWndEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (!m_wndMenuBar.Create(this))
    {
        TRACE(_T("Failed to create menu-bar\n"));
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY);

    CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceMenuFocus(FALSE);

    m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);

    CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);
    EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

    return 0;
}
```

I have another menu resource IDR_MAINFRAME_02.

[image: Menu resources]

How is it possible to switch from IDR_MAINFRAME to IDR_MAINFRAME_02 during runtime ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and it will be done automatically for different types of documents template. It is your case/wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the menu 'owned' (and displayed) by a `CMFCMenuBar` (at almost any time, I think) simply by loading the new menu into an `HMENU` object and then re-creating the menu bar object using that loaded object.

In your case, a member function of the `CMainFrame` class to do this would look something like this:

```cpp
void CMainFrame::SwitchMenu(int menuID) // Pass, e.g., IDR_MAINFRAME_02 here
{
    HMENU newMenu = LoadMenu(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(menuID));
    m_wndMenuBar.CreateFromMenu(newMenu, TRUE, TRUE);
}
```

Note: When I tested this in one of my MFC MDI apps, it worked as expected (I use a very similar technique to update the menu bar when I load plugins that add new sub-menus). However, the 'framework' appears to remember the new menu and loads that (by default) next time the app is started. So, to use the **original** menu *each time* when you start up, you could just call this function with `IDR_MAINFRAME` (without the `_02` suffix) during program initialisation (near the end of your `OnCreate` function).

---

[Documentation for the `CreateFromMenu` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=msvc-170#createfrommenu).